# Hibernate/Spring transaction - "Bad" flush order

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

In my app (Spring Boot based) I am using Hibernate and have custom repository like that:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRepoEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value="SELECT NEXTVAL('mytable')", nativeQuery=true)
    Long nextId();

    @Procedure(procedureName = "SCHEMA2.save_2", outputParameterName = "res")
    String callProcedure(@Param("prm_nrid") Long nr);
}
```

In my manager have a method with the following business logic:

```
@Transactional
String invokeProcedure1() {
    Long id = myRepo.nextId();
    return myRepo.callProcedure(id);
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate performs the two actions randomly and out of order because there is no db "relationship".
Is there a way (preferably without explicitly using *flush()*) to have *nexId* invoked before *callProcedure*?

Thank you all!

Comment: Adding a call to flush seems to me like the most straightforward fix. You could set flush mode to auto.

Answer (score 0):

These are native queries which are executed immediately. I don't know how your real application looks like, but the code you posted will first run the `nextval` query and only then call the stored procedure.